# How to add pod as a target?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, target

I created a pod(Rkeyboard) at GitHub. it was about to custom keyboard. when we want to add custom keyboard in project then it is necessary that we must create a target. But when I install the pod it doesn't create the target as i did not include any target in pod. **Please tell me the way how to add pod as a target that can run with main target.**
The link of pod is https://github.com/dineshsharma1/Rkeyboard
Any direction or help will appreciate.
Thanks in advance

1. tried to edit pod file with installer
2. tried to edit run script
   but not succeed

   - project is running successfully but can't see keyboard in setting because of target

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Podfile** and add the following code

```
target 'TargetName' do
 // add any pods to be installed for target
end
```

Dont forget to `pod install`

Before all the steps above, your XCode needs to have the target matched with name you give in your **Podfile**. Good luck!

Comment: it will simply install a pod not as a target.